# Get all layers from gdb file

Tags: file-geodatabase, file-geodatabase-api

I am trying to get all layers from gdb file.I am using file geodatabase API. I am unable to find any help regarding how to get all layers and then read that layers.

Right Now i am using
 Geodatabase geodatabase = Geodatabase.Open("../../samples/data/Querying.gdb");

```
//   String allTables = geodatabase.DataSetTypes.;
```

I have tried several things like get datasetypes and from there get Tables but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by *layer* you mean *table* or *featureclass* then it is quite straightforward:

```cs
foreach (var ds in gdb.GetChildDatasets("\\", string.Empty))
{
    Console.WriteLine(ds);
}
```

Comment: sor thanks for replying me back what i understand is getchildDatasets should return all tables placed in gdb folder? Am i right? As it is returning only 2 tables and there are more then 10 .gdtable files

Comment: It returns all _datasets_ inside the gdb: Featureclasses, Tables, Relationshipclasses, ... The .gdbtable files on the filesystem are not (geo) tables but are used by ArcGIS internally.

Comment: BTW sir i want to read shape files so I have read all data in table from above cpde which you have mention but i am confused in how to get shape files from them?

Comment: @MuneemHabib Could you please post this as a separate qusetion?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167762/read-all-geospatial-data

Comment: i am using sample [project providd by fileGeodatabase API . I have used getchildsets to gett all tables but in sample its opening table CITIES which is not at all returned by getchilddataset. Any Idea?